# Identify same/related calendar event from different calendars

Tags: icalendar, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I need to retrieve the attendee list from an organizer's calendar. To do this, I need to identify with certainty the same event in the another user's calendar.

Exchange is linking the related events, but that property might not be exposed over Microsoft Graph API and the Event `id` does not match.

So far I could identify that `iCalUId` does match. Of course, start and end dates should match also. The subject will most likely not match because rooms often transform this property.

1. Can anyone confirm, that `iCalUId` is always the same for related events in different calendars?
2. Can I filter Microsoft Graph events by `iCalUId` property (or directly access it using this key)?

**Update:**

I have found [this article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/event), which theoretically confirms my first question. I would appreciate if somebody could confirm this based on practical experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iCalUId` property is static, even across external recipients. This `iCalUId` property reflects the `UID` property defined in the iCalendar specification ([RFC 5545 § 3.8.4.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.7)) as a "persistent, globally unique identifier for the calendar component".

As for pulling it from Microsoft Graph, you can use the `$filter` query parameter of the `events` collection to fetch a given `iCalUId`:

```
/v1.0/me/events?$filter=iCalUId eq '{UID}'
```

You can try this in Graph Explorer using [this sample](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/events?$filter=iCalUId%20eq%20%27040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000001DE8F4B16728D3010000000000000000100000005232C5046A593E4EB2CB35F84B01A566%27&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. And thank you for correcting my grammar. But I don't know why have you removed the root cause of my problem from the post. I would not need this at all if the Exchange server farm behind Office 365 would maintain attendee list in the room's calendar.

Comment: On the other hand, it seems that filtering does not work for CalendarView. Although the iCalUId of the two events are the same, filtering returns empty result. Filtering Events collection, however, return the result, but only for SingleEvent and SeriesMaster types. Occurrences and Exceptions are not returned.

Comment: That is correct, you're only going to get back the singles and masters from `events`. The `CalendarView` is entirely based on a date range.

Comment: Does anyone know if they changed filering in beta?  It seems that they changed iCalUId to uid, but no longer allow to filter on it?  This is a big issue for us, as it is the connector between Outlook Com objects and Graph.